# How to get page contents (CASPER JS) if needed content loads only after js hover on already loaded (ready) page?

Tags: jquery, parsing, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Try to scrape some contents from [here](http://lamoda.ru) only for my own use.

But there is a problem. With the help of Casper JS i can easily get page DOM, but there is a block (".menu-dropdowns"), which is dynamically loaded only after page is full loaded, ready and then you hover any main navigation item (".menu__category-trigger").

Besides it seems that Casper doesn't execute js on page at all. Maybe i don't understand smth, but js hover toggleClass and other scripts used on original page are not available on my page)

My code example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts:  [
        'includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'
    ]
    verbose: true
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');

var url = 'http://www.lamoda.ru';

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.echo(this.getPageContent());
});

casper.run();
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since I used Casperjs.  Can you use Casper JS to move the mouse to the ".menu_category-trigger" element then use a "waitforselector" to watch for your content to load?

Comment: @fatfantasma, tanks for comment, i'll take your advice)